# bosh_lite management interface for cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I just installed cloud_foundry locally with bosh_lite. Pushing a sample app and the command line works like a charm.

I assume there should be some kind of management interface for it. Yet the docs about bosh_lite do not mention where this is located. I tried 'https://10.244.0.34.xip.io/', but that gives me

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('10.244.0.34.xip.io') does not exist.
```

I can also find the URL under which to access my app using

```
cf apps
```

The app works fine. Possibly the command line is the only management interface for open source CF?

Comment: That is correct, the command line is the only open source management interface maintained by core contributors.  Was there some particular information you wanted to see?

Comment: That's fine. Just wanted to know if there is a similar web interface to the one provided by PivotalCF. But I guess the command line will show all necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post an answer to this, no.  There's no web gui available out-of-the-box with bosh-lite.  The command line utility should give you all the information you need though.

If you want a gui, you might try the [admin-ui](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/admin-ui).  I haven't personally used it, but it's should give you a gui.